# Information from first form to second form swing java

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 forms. In the first form, I create an object `suggestion`. Then I have to do something with it and submit it to the second form. How can I open a second window after filling out the first form?

This is my first form:

```
public class FormNum1 extends JFrame {
    JButton clearConfermation, conferm;
    JLabel dateofDeparture, dateofArrival, cityFrom, cityTo;
    JTextField dateofDepartureTextField, dateofArrivalTextField, cityFromTextField, cityToTextField;
    static Suggestion suggestion;
    Boolean n = false;
    JFrame form1 = new JFrame("form1");
    ActionListener actionPerformed;
    public FormNum1(){
        form1.setVisible(true);
        form1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form1.setSize(1200,250);
        //setResizable(false);
        form1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        form1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        clearConfermation = new JButton("Make clear");
        conferm = new JButton("Confirm information ");
        dateofDeparture = new JLabel("Date of Departure");
        dateofArrival = new JLabel("Date of Arrival");
        cityFrom = new JLabel("City From");
        cityTo = new JLabel("City to");
        dateofDepartureTextField = new JTextField(10);
        dateofArrivalTextField = new JTextField(10);
        cityFromTextField = new JTextField(10);
        cityToTextField = new JTextField(10);
        form1.add(clearConfermation);
        form1.add(conferm);
        form1.add(dateofDeparture);
        form1. add(dateofDepartureTextField);
        form1.add(dateofArrival);
        form1.add(dateofArrivalTextField);
        form1.add(cityFrom);
        form1.add(cityFromTextField);
        form1.add(cityTo);
        form1.add(cityToTextField);
        actionPerformed = new InformationFromFormOne();
        conferm.addActionListener(actionPerformed);
        clearConfermation.addActionListener(actionPerformed);
    }


    class InformationFromFormOne implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == conferm){
                String dateOfDeparture = (dateofDepartureTextField.getText());
                String dateOfArrival   = (dateofArrivalTextField.getText());
                String cityFrom   = (cityFromTextField.getText());
                String cityTo  = (cityToTextField.getText());
                suggestion = new Suggestion(dateOfDeparture, dateOfArrival, true, cityFrom, cityTo);

                setVisible(false);
                form1.dispose();
            }

            if (e.getSource() == clearConfermation){
                dateofArrivalTextField.setText(null);
                dateofDepartureTextField.setText(null);
                cityFromTextField.setText(null);
                cityToTextField.setText(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My second form is

```
public class FormNum2 extends JFrame{
    static JFrame form2 = new JFrame("form2");

    public FormNum2()  {
        form2.setSize(1200,600);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        form2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        form2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main extends Thread{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FormNum1 form1 = new FormNum1();
        FormNum2 form2 = new FormNum2();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Confirm" is spelled as such, not as "conferm". Same goes for confirmation. Didn't want to change it in case it was used elsewhere

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `form1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` (sigh) You ***really*** should check the Java docs for methods used, rather than just 'flying blind' as it seems is currently happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first frame processing set the second frame to `visible`, put `FormNum2 .setVisible(true);` to show the second form.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The Answer was accepted by OP so it helped him solve his problem, don't know why I got downvoted though.

Comment: Actually I didn't respond because OP was pretty fast in accepting answer, so didn't feel the need to respond after that, I used to have the same problem as OP so I answered immediately after reading the code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open the second window after the filling of the object in the first then you should call FormNum2 form2 = new FormNum2() after the object is filled. It seems like you would want to add this line after form1.dispose().

Comment: Did *you* try that?

Comment: I didn't try it my self, but by looking at your code it should work. Did you try it? Did it fix your problem? Also @GherbiHicham's answer should also work. Just make sure to remove form2.setVisible(true); from the constructor in Form2.

Comment: Think carefully about the effect of `form1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` & `form2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` .. What will happen when ***either*** window is closed? *"by looking at your code it should work"* You seem to be under the impression you are replying to the person who asked the original question. I can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers) ..